# Operating on a masked array, and then operating on a different part of the same array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, mask

So i'm trying to implement a symlog style colour scale in matplotlib, I'm doing this by scaling my values onto the region of 0-1 and then using custom colourbar ticks and labels.

I'm scaling my values in three sections, using masks, but it's not working as I expect it should;

I first do this:

```
negMask = ma.masked_greater_equal(Z, -10**thresh, copy=True).mask
posMask = ma.masked_less_equal(Z, 10**thresh, copy=True).mask
linMask = ma.masked_outside(Z, -10**thresh, 10**thresh, copy=True).mask
```

To get the three masks i'll want. Then I start scaling the to the 0-1 region:

```
sizeNeg = int(np.ceil(log10(-minZ)) - thresh)
sizePos = int(np.ceil(log10(maxZ)) - thresh)
sizeLin = 2
totSize = sizeNeg + sizePos + sizeLin

Z.mask = negMask
Z = (-np.log10(-Z) - thresh) / totSize
```

If I stop here, and plot it, then it behaves as expected, here's a small section of the plot:

[image]

Where you can see it plots the negative values, but then not the positive parts - as they're masked.

So then I change the mask to the one for the positive values;

```
Z.mask = posMask
Z = (np.log10(Z) - thresh + sizeNeg + sizeLin) / totSize
```

But when I do this, all the values that were masked before, are now all just `1.0`. The data that was there is gone.

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 11 2012, 05:25:09) 
[GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from numpy.ma import masked_where as mw
>>> a = np.arange(0,10,1)
>>> a = mw(False, a)
>>> a
masked_array(data = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9],
             mask = False,
       fill_value = 999999)

>>> mask1 = mw(a>4,a).mask
>>> mask2 = mw(a<6,a).mask
>>> mask1
array([False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> mask2
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> a.mask = mask1
>>> a
masked_array(data = [0 1 2 3 4 -- -- -- -- --],
             mask = [False False False False False  True  True  True  True  True],
       fill_value = 999999)

>>> a = np.log10(a)
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log10
>>> a
masked_array(data = [-- 0.0 0.301029995664 0.47712125472 0.602059991328 -- -- -- -- --],
             mask = [ True False False False False  True  True  True  True  True],
       fill_value = 999999)

>>> a.mask = mask2
>>> a
masked_array(data = [-- -- -- -- -- -- 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0],
             mask = [ True  True  True  True  True  True False False False False],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

Using `np.log10` on a masked array spoils the masked values, so that when you unmask them they are just all `1.0`.

I know I could split my array into three separate ones, one for each region, but how do I combine them again afterwards?

Comment: Show the (full) traceback as well, please.

Comment: Note: the last line of your question is chopped off; perhaps not important, but probably good to edit your question and conclude the sentence.

Comment: Try using `numpy.ma.log10()` in your example. Not sure if that will help solve your original problem, since the plot routines (mpl?) may not use the `numpy.ma` routines, but perhaps for that, [`MaskedArray.compress()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.MaskedArray.compress.html) can be of use

Comment: `numpy.ma.log10()` seems to have solved it. Thanks.